# Transform3d’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type

Tags: eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I'm a beginner in ROS and I was working around this tutorial: [Coding a real time Cartesian controller with Eigen](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Coding%20a%20realtime%20Cartesian%20controller%20with%20Eigen)

However, the following declaration:
" typedef Eigen::Transform3d                CartPose;"
leads to the error:
"Transform3d’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type".

Any suggestion is very much welcome!

Yuquan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42836/transform3d%E2%80%99-in-namespace-%E2%80%98eigen%E2%80%99-does-not-name-a-type/) by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-09-02**:
Could you post some more context? Which version of ROS? Surrounding lines of the error? These types of errors mostly occur if you are missing '#include' statements, or don't have the (proper versions of) headers installed.

**Comment by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on 2012-09-02**:
Yes, I'm using ubuntu 11.10 and ROS-electric. I guess probably it's a problem about eigen2 or eigen3. I'll try. Thanks!

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-09-02**:
It's probably easier to edit your original question, instead of trying to use comments for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solved this problem. As indicated in [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Eigen2ToEigen3.html), Transform3f should be replace with Affine3f. Likewise, I should use Affine3d rather than Transform3d.

The detailed definition could be found [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#ga1cee3e45cad60050d3c94cf603e2ff45)

Thank you for all the replies!

---

Originally posted by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) with karma: 68 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1